# bash script not the same as SSH console

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, debian, sh

I have this command

```
tar -czf /var/log/apache2/logfile_backups/dBackup_$(date "+%d-%m-%Y").tar.gz /var/log/apache2/ --exclude=/var/log/apache2/logfile_backups --exclude='*.sh'
```

***First***, I run this command in a SSH-Console (Putty), everything works great!

***Second***, I write a bash-Script (myscript.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -czf /var/log/apache2/logfile_backups/dBackup_$(date "+%d-%m-%Y").tar.gz /var/log/apache2/ --exclude=/var/log/apache2/logfile_backups --exclude='*.sh'
```

And start this script in SSH-Console with `bash ./myscript.sh`, but the result at the end is not the same. The `tar`-command ignores the second `--exclude` parameter.

**What's wrong?
I think, a bash script is the same as a SSH-console like Putty.**

Comment: They are probably different versions of `tar`. Try `tar --version` to find out.

Comment: No, the file versions are the same and the bash script run under "root"-user, the "root"-user is also logged in in the ssh-console

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the result of your two command please. I'm sure it could help.

Answer (score 0):

As an example I found on net:

a simple backup script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash          
OF=/var/my-backup-$(date +%Y%m%d).tgz
tar -cZf $OF /home/me/
```

So try to change your command to:

```
tar  -cZf /var/log/apache2/logfile_backups/dBackup_$(date +%Y%m%d).tgz.gz /var/log/apache2/ --exclude=/var/log/apache2/logfile_backups --exclude='*.sh'
```

1) What distros are you using?

2) Are you running the command and script exactly at one server or not?

3) Try `chmod +x script.sh` and then invoke it by saying `./scipt.sh`

4) Specify tar version by saying `tar --version`

You said:

I think, a bash script is the same as a SSH-console like Putty.

Be sure that they are the same as each other but working with terminal over Linux is much easier